# Mysql statement to list tables of certain columns?

Tags: mysql, identity-column

I'm trying to figure out the foreign keys relationship within my MySQL databases.

I have many tables that has the "mydomain_id" column located in other tables.

Is there a command line I can use to list all tables that has that particular column?

Comment: Nope, no such thing exists, sorry. The only way I see is a pretty crude workaround: you could use the `mysqldump` utility with the no-data flag to dump the table structures and pipe the output into a `grep` call to filter by that column...

Comment: Well, you could use the information schema: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT `table_name`
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME IN ('name') AND
    TABLE_SCHEMA='symfony_backend';
```

**Gives:** (*all the tables listed below exist in my database `symfony_backend`*)

```
table_name
'child'
'country'
'league'
'parent'
'player'
'schools'
'student'
'team'
'user'
```

You can feed more column names with: `COLUMN_NAME IN ('name', 'another_column', 'and_another_one')`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
    AND column_name = 'mydomain_id'
```

Comment: A code-only question is considered low quality.  A brief description of exactly what the code does would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe when you've earned it